# Docked Cell that scrolls?

Tags: front-end, notebooks, cells, customization, docked-cell

I use two finger movement on my trackpad for scrolling a notebook page up and down.  Is it possible to make a docked cells that scrolls to the left and right using a two finger movement on the trackpad?

The reason I ask is because sometimes my notebook window is not full screen.  My notebook needs to be in full screen mode to see the entire docked cell.  I have lots of buttons that can't be seen if it is not. I don't want to make the buttons smaller than they already are.

It would be nice to have a way to scroll to the right and left to reach the buttons without resizing the notebook window.  Is this possible?

Comment: You could wrap the content with Pane with Scrollbars and it seem it partially works, can't use the bar itself but arrows at its ends are. Maybe a grid of buttons is a solution, or do you insist on having one?

Comment: Thank you Kuba.  I would like to be able to use two finger gesture instead of manually clicking the scrollbar.  I would prefer if the scrollbar wasn't present at all.  I could do as you suggested and create a grid instead of row, but was trying to avoid this as it would make my toolbar taller which cuts into my viewing area.

Comment: Try `GestureHandler` with `Alignment` or a `ScrollPosition`, can't test now, no pad around ;)

Comment: I will!  Thanks again Kuba.  If this works, I'll post my solution.

Comment: It looks like the gesture handler is for touch devices only.  It doesn't recognize the gestures on the trackpad on my mac.

Comment: I searched around some more.  I couldn't find any way to add scrolling  functionality to a toolbar.  I have opted to use multiple rows and the following option for Grid:   ItemSize->{{Scaled[3.5/8],Scaled[5.5/8]}}.  This keeps things clean and allows me to resize the window and keep all buttons flush against the left and right side of the toolbar while I resize.  Thanks Kuba for the help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using MMA 11.0.0 the following works to create a scrollable docked cell:

```
setScrollingDockedCell[expr_] :=
  SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[],
   DockedCells ->
    Cell[BoxData@ToBoxes@
       Pane[expr,
        ImageSize -> Scaled[1]
        ]
     ]
   ];
```

Note that the `ImageSize -> Scaled[1]` is crucial here. Without an explicit `ImageSize` no scrolling occurs. Scaled[1] sticks the expression on a single line. Something ludicrous like `ImageSize -> 100000000` will also work.

This works with all of the expressions I've tried:

```
setScrollingDockedCell@
 Row@Table[
   With[{i = i},
    PasteButton[i]
    ],
   {i, Range[100]}
   ]

setScrollingDockedCell@
 Grid@Table[
   With[{i = i},
    PasteButton[Row@{i, j}, {i, j}]
    ],
   {i, Range[3]},
   {j, Range[100]}
   ]

setScrollingDockedCell@
 Pane[Graphics[{
    Disk[{0, 0}, 1000],
    {White, Disk[{0, 0}, {100, 900}]},
    {Green, Disk[{0, 0}, {75, 750}]},
    {Black, Disk[{0, 0}, {50, 500}]},
    Disk[{2000, 0}, 1000],
    {White, Disk[{2000, 0}, {100, 900}]},
    {Green, Disk[{2000, 0}, {75, 750}]},
    {Black, Disk[{2000, 0}, {50, 500}]}
    }, AspectRatio -> Full,
   ImageSize -> 1000],
  {Automatic, 25}]
```

All of those work

It seems to balk when there's a lot of blank space in the expression though:

```
setScrollingDockedCell@Range[1000]
```

That only starts scrolling when you have the cursor over one of the expression elements (a number/bracket/comma I mean)

Perhaps this is new as of 11 but I don't have a copy of 10 to test. It is very useful for things like tabbed windows though.

Comment: Works in 10.3 as well.